# UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows folder. WSL 2

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm using an npm project in WSL but when I start, it gives me this error:

```
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current folder.
UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows folder.
```

I already tried using net use and pushd but it still don't work

```
C:\Windows\system32>net use X: \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-20.04\home\webtrunk\web-trunk
```

System error 67.

The network name was not found.

Comment: System error 67.

The network name was not found.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using exactly? Do you have Hardened UNC Paths enabled or disabled?